# Is it possible to use unicode Class names in Grails?

Tags: eclipse, grails, unicode

If I try to create a domain class in grails with unicode characters such as `class Mãe` and running `grails create-domain-class Mãe`, the characters with accents disappear, and the next character becomes uppercase, in this case turning into `class ME`.

Is there any way to use accents in class names with grails?

Thanks

PS: Eclipse is set to create files in utf-8, and the classes's attributes can be used with accents with no problem, not the class name though

Comment: IMHO it's very bad idea to use different language than English for naming in software projects. Using different languages including their special characters and diacritics is unholy idea

Comment: It is very common in countries that don't speak english to name variables in the local language, but usually diacritics are skipped(it would become `class Mae`). If I'm not able to put diacritics in the class name, I also will not put them in it's attributes to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that since I'm also not from English speaking country. I still consider it bad practice although it's common. I really support the idea to at least not use special characters and diacritics in naming..

Comment: @dmahapatro What suggestions? He simply stated his opinion. I understand why it can be a bad idea to use diacritics, but first of all this system is going to be in portuguese whether I want it or not. What I am trying to find out is if there is a way to enable diacritics in a class name in a grails project, because I know attributes do work with diacritics(although I won't add it if class name doesn't). If it does, then I can discuss with my colleagues whether it is worth it or not.

Comment: Correct, it's not the answer just my opinion. If it's possible to use unicode characters in Grails class names is unknown to me and I won't spend my time trying to find out because of my opinion on the matter..